# mysql join the 2 tables to produce following output

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `users` and `user_fingerprints`.

[image: table]

How do I combine the two tables to produce the output?

I tried

```
select u.id, u.name, 
case f.finger (when 0 then 'y' else 'n' end) '0',
case f.finger (when 1 then 'y' else 'n' end) '1',
case f.finger (when 2 then 'y' else 'n' end) '2',
case f.finger (when 3 then 'y' else 'n' end) '3', 
case f.finger (when 4 then 'y' else 'n' end) '4',
case f.finger (when 5 then 'y' else 'n' end) '5', 
case f.finger (when 6 then 'y' else 'n' end) '6'
from user u left join user_fingerprint f
on u.id=f.user_id
group by u.id
```

but the result will only take one row from same id and update it in the output table. when i use `max` function, it worked, but is there any way without using `max`?

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregation function:

```
select u.id, u.name, 
       max(case f.finger when 0 then 'y' else 'n' end) as '0',
       max(case f.finger when 1 then 'y' else 'n' end) as '1',
       max(case f.finger when 2 then 'y' else 'n' end) as '2',
       max(case f.finger when 3 then 'y' else 'n' end) as '3', 
       max(case f.finger when 4 then 'y' else 'n' end) as '4',
       max(case f.finger when 5 then 'y' else 'n' end) as '5', 
       max(case f.finger when 6 then 'y' else 'n' end) as '6'
from user u left join
     user_fingerprint f
     on u.id = f.user_id
group by u.id;
```

I would suggest that you reconsider using integers as column aliases.  Looks doomed to be confusing . . . or worse, to cause hard to spot errors.

Also, note that `max()` works because `'y' > 'n'`.  There are other methods if you don't want to depend on that.

This also assumes that you want one summary row for each column.  Otherwise you might want something like `group_concat()`.

Comment: thank you, is there any other way without using aggregate func?

Comment: @tyty . . . You have an aggregation query.  Aggregation functions are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why don't you want to use function `max`, without `max` I think you can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, u.name, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('0', GROUP_CONCAT(f.finger) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END `0`, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('1', GROUP_CONCAT(f.finger) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END `1`, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('2', GROUP_CONCAT(f.finger) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END `2`, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('3', GROUP_CONCAT(f.finger) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END `3`, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('4', GROUP_CONCAT(f.finger) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END `4`, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('5', GROUP_CONCAT(f.finger) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END `5`, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('6', GROUP_CONCAT(f.finger) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END `6`
FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN user_fingerprint f ON u.id = f.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will concat all `finger` for each `user` and separated by comma, then [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) will return the index of first parameter in second parameter.